# How to mix asynchronous request handling with synchronous in microservice architecture

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, synchronous, api-gateway

I have an API gateway that interacts with services. At the moment, the gateway accepts HTTP requests from various external servers, calls a certain service, waits for processing (for example, transactions, authorizations, etc.) and returns a response to the external server. But now one of the servers wants us to accept asynchronous requests, but only for transaction processing (only for certain endpoints). How should I properly mix async and sync request handling. Should I handle this in the gateway or in the service that process the transactions?

I drew simple diagrams showing the request processing flow.
[Requests flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lLiH.jpg)